# Images.xcassets AppIcon and Launch image

Tags: xcode5, xcasset

I am trying to learn the new way to add icons and Splash screen to iPhone applications ([asset catalog)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH1-SW1).  The new Images.xcassets kind of tripped me up at first but then I started getting the hang of it.  There are even, at least, two different sites out there that will transform your icon into all the different sizes needed for icons on both iPhone and Android:  [Icon Slayer](http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/icon_slayer/#.UsLzX3madfM) and [Makeappicon.com](http://makeappicon.com/ios7icon#)  **Pretty cool!**

But in my "playing around" with all these great tools and learning a lot, I learned that to create the Splash Screen is discouraged by Apple and that these tools do not create a Launch Image for you.  So I decided to just remove my LaunchImage set from Images.xcassets.

Now, when I clean and build I receive the following error:

> /Users/pdl/Development/TestBackground/TestBackground/Images.xcassets:
>   None of the input catalogs contained a matching launch image set named
>   "LaunchImage".

So, then I removed my AppIcon set from Images.xcassets and when I ran a clean and build I received the same error for my AppIcon.  I solved the problem by deleting my Images.xcassets completely and recreating it from start.

Just curious if anybody has any idea where these configurations are stored?  Should be easier to fix than delete and recreate.  Know what I mean?

I hope to get some help by also giving some help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have found it, but anyway(relevant for Xcode 6):

Select project file and then select target in question. In General tab there is "App Icons and launch images" section under "Deployment info". In "Launch Images Source" you can either select necessary launch image asset or select "Do not use asset catalogs".

Comment: Yeah, I had already found out how to do this but the info is great in-case somebody else is looking for the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I ran into the same problem as you, I had selected "**Do not use asset catalogs**" but the project was still trying to load the launch image from a catalog.

If you look down in your Build Settings, you will see **Asset Catalog Compiler - Options**. You will see your *App Icon Set Name* & *Launch Image Set Name*. The Launch Image Set Name was still set, I removed this (left it blank) and ran a clean build. This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was missing

Comment: This fixed it for me. Except in my case I had to blank-out the AppIcon option. Thanks!